# Image in UIImage resize when draw on it

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

When I load a image to my UIImageView and would like draw on it. Then will change the ratio of the image. Can somebody tell me what is here the wrong?

Thanks

**Before drawing**

[image: Before drawing]

**When you drawing**

[image: When you drawing]

```
func drawLines(fromPoint:CGPoint,toPoint:CGPoint) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
    imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: fromPoint.x, y: fromPoint.y))
    context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: toPoint.x, y: toPoint.y))

    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(brushSize)
    context?.setStrokeColor(UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: opacityValue).cgColor)

    context?.strokePath()

    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying scale the image and the drawn lines? Can we see the code you've written to do that?

Comment: Swap     imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)) with  imageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.width, height: imageView.height))